# How to filter out layers with QgsMapLayerComboBox?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qt-designer

I am using Qt Designer 4.8.5 to develop a plugin (with QGIS 2.14.3-Essen).

I recently started to use `QgsMapLayerComboBox` widgets instead of the conventional `Combo Box` widget. However, I want to filter out a number of layers so that only a few are shown.

When I used the `Combo box` widget, here is the code:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
main_group = root.findGroup('Main group')
layers = []
for group in main_group.children():
    for layer in group.children():                
        layers.append(layer.layerName())
self.dockwidget.combo_box.clear()
self.dockwidget.combo_box.addItems(sorted(layers))
```

---

How can I translate the above code to work with `QgsMapLayerComboBox`? I have seen the [QgsMapLayerComboBox.setExceptedLayerList()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html#a971f6710119167497816a255813bf17f) but not exactly sure how to create such a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess it was easier than I thought, I just had to create a list of `QgsMapLayers` from a group I want **excluded** in the `QgsMapLayerComboBox`:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
other_group = root.findGroup('Other group')
layers = []
for group in other_group.children():
    for layer in group.children():
        layerList = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.layerName())[0]
        layers.append(layerList)
self.dockwidget.combo_box.setExceptedLayerList(layers)
```